# WebDriverIO/Jasmine/TypeScript - "Cannot Use Import Statement Outside of a Module"

Tags: node.js, typescript, jasmine, babeljs, webdriver-io

I've seen this issue posted a ton, and I've tried all the solutions, but none seem to work for me.  I'd greatly appreciate any help/advice, I've pulled my hair out trying to figure this out.

Here's my setup...

I'm using WebDriverIO with Jasmine and Typescript to run some automation tests. I'm doing cross-platform testing, and need to import `import {Platform} from 'react-native'` to add some platform-specific code (selectors are different in Win32 from MacOS, for example).

When I run a spec file, I get the following error:

> [0-0] 2021-12-07T00:22:58.202Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
> [0-0] (node:26568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
> import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
> at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
> at Module._compile (C:\Users\my_path\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
> at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
> at Object.newLoader [as .js]

Here's what I've done:

- Added integration for TypeScript+Babel for WebDriverIO according to the documentation.
- In my WebDriverIO config file, I've added the following line of code:

```
   beforeSession: function (config, capabilities, specs) {
      require('@babel/register');
    },
```

Here are all relevant files:

**Package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
...
"ts-node": "^8.10.1",
"tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
"typescript": "3.8.3",
"webdriverio": "^6.5.0",
"appium-mac2-driver": "0.14.1",
"@wdio/appium-service": "^6.5.0",
"@wdio/cli": "^6.5.0",
"@wdio/jasmine-framework": "^6.5.0",
"@wdio/local-runner": "^6.5.0",
"@wdio/spec-reporter": "^6.5.0",
"@wdio/sync": "^6.5.0",
"@babel/core": "^7.8.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.0",
"@babel/register": "^7.8.0",
"@babel/cli": "^7.8.0"
```

},

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [['@babel/preset-env']],
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*"],
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "types": ["@wdio/sync", "@wdio/jasmine-framework", "node", "@types/jasmine"]
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

**wdio.conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
  // Extra not-needed condigs here

  services: ['appium'],
  appium: {
    logPath: './reports/',
    args: {
      port: '4723',
    },
  },

  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: jasmineDefaultTimeout,
    requires: ['@babel/register']
  },

  /*
   ** ===================
   ** Hooks
   ** ===================
  /**
   * Gets executed before test execution begins. At this point you can access to all global
   * variables like `browser`. It is the perfect place to define custom commands.
   * @param {Array.<Object>} capabilities list of capabilities details
   * @param {Array.<String>} specs List of spec file paths that are to be run
   */
  before: function () {
    require('ts-node').register({ files: true }); // NEED THIS HERE
    require('@babel/register'); // DOES NOT WORK
    browser.maximizeWindow();
  },
```

Does anyone have any tips on what could be going wrong? I've tried so many different things and nothing seems to work. I'd greatly appreciate it!